How to adjust the position of accent marks in TFM files?
As shown in the image, I have adjusted the italic Latin characters of the STIX font. However, when using the adjusted font, all characters display correctly except for the accent mark on the letter A, which shifts to the right.
I tried adjusting the width of both the accent mark and the letter A in the TFM file. The issue is resolved only when I decrease the width of the letter A or increase the width of the accent mark. However, this approach affects the alignment of accent marks on other letters.
I would like to ask if there is a way to adjust the position of the accent mark specifically for the uppercase letter A in the TFM file (or perhaps in another file?).


welcome! is this in maths mode? the tag suggests so, but your question should mention this, if so. how are you adjusting these in the tfm exactly? tfms are not meant to be edited directly. typically, they are generated from human-readable sources. to change one, in the absence of the source, i would convert it to text format first. but if you have the original source, it is generally easier to change that. what adjustments have you made to the characters? and what is the source of the output you show?

note that the accents are displaced for the B and C as well. the effect just isn't quite so obvious.

@cfr You're right. I used the tftopl script to convert the TFM file into a readable format, made my modifications, and then used the pltotf script to convert it back to TFM.

ok. so can you edit your question to show us what you changed and which file? and where did you change the glyphs? in the pfb? which one? and what code produced the output you show? try to put yourself in the position of somebody trying to help you. what do you need to know to understand the question?

@cfr Hi, I modified stix-mathit.pfb and replaced the lowercase and uppercase letters with the corresponding content from STIXGeneral-Italic.pfb（Only the uppercase and lowercase letters were replaced.）.

please add that information to your question and show (1) what changes you made to the TFM and (2) what code you used to produce the output you show.
